# Error 404 on next page url requests using Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to fetch data from Flipkart.com via python API. The response has a `'nextUrl'` tag which I am trying to fetch to get additional data. But it keeps giving me a error 404.

My code:

```
    url = "https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/v2/returns"
    next_url = "https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/v2{0}"

    payload = {'source':return_source,
                'createdAfter':createdAfter}

    response = self.session.get(url, params=payload)
    orders = []
    resp_json = response.json()
    print resp_json

    for each in resp_json['returnItems']:
        orders.append(each)

    try:
        while resp_json['hasMore'] == True:
            new_url = ''
            new_url = next_url.format(resp_json['nextUrl'])
            response = self.session.get(new_url)
            resp_json = response.json()
            for each in resp_json['returnItems']:
                orders.append(each)
    except:
        print "Next page return url not working"
```

The first response I get:

```
{u'nextUrl': u'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', u'hasMore': True, u'returnItems': [{u'orderId': u'OD40476241666874334000', u'returnId': 4058426316, u'orderItemId': u'4476166687432143400', u'expectedDate': None, u'updatedDate': None, u'subReason': None, u'shipmentStatus': u'in_transit', u'comments': u'Customer requested to cancel the order', u'shipmentId': None, u'reason': u'order_cancelled', u'courierName': None, u'status': u'cancelled', u'trackingId': u'5962062676508084', u'createdDate': u'2015-12-28T23:10:23+05:30', u'approvedOn': None, u'sellerId': u'test_seller_1', u'type': u'courier_return', u'orderDate': u'2015-12-22T05:15:53.000Z', u'quantity': 1}]}
```

What I am doing wrong while trying to fetch additional pages?

It keeps giving me status code 404 for `'nextUrl'` only.

Comment: Have you tried to retrieve that subsequent url using another client? Maybe it is the host that is erroneous, not your code.

Comment: No. I have only 1 client account. That's what i was thinking too. because i have a similar method and i can access that method fine. So i think its a problem from the host side..